# sshd subsystem specific configuration

Tags: ssh, unix

Is there a way to specify below values specific to a ssh-subsystem in sshd_config?

ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax

For example, I have a subsystem abc then I want to define client alive interval and client alive count only for this subsystem. How do I specify the same in sshd_config?

Subsystem abc abcd

ClientAliveInterval 10

ClientAliveCountMax 22

Doing so is applicable to all ssh sessions.

Kindly help